# Store a string in two seperate variables in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
$string = 'Product Name | 43.39';
```

I want to sepreate it into two variables

```
$productName
```

and

```
$productPrice
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this

```
list($productName, $productPrice) = explode(' | ', $string);
```

Virtually the same, but I love one liners :)

Comment: I don't mind people editing my answers but please put a note as to what you have changed and why, regards.

Comment: you can see the revisions and comments by clicking the link that shows how long ago the last edit was http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10179606/revisions

Comment: It was trivial, but it made it not my answer! Thanks though I did not know about that feature!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for this.

```
$string = 'Product Name | 43.39';
$array = explode(' | ',$string);
$productName = $array[0]; //will echo Product Name
$productPrice = $array[1]; //will echo 43.39
```

This function basically takes your string and splits it wherever it sees the delimiter.

A shorter version of this would basically be:

```
$string = 'Product Name | 43.39';
list($productName, $productPrice) = explode(' | ', $string);
```

It does exactly the same thing it is just on one line and may be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version :

```
$string = 'Product Name | 43.39';
list($productName,$productPrice) = explode(' | ',$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$string = 'Product Name | 43.39';
list($productName , $productPrice) = explode(" | ",$string);
```